# Can we ask for reviews of data models or ER diagrams on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, database, database-design

Is it OK to ask questions concerning the data model of a specific system on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I think you can ask it on [Programmers stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm not sure it's suitable for http://dba.stackexchange.com/ but you should browse over there just in case.  Perhaps they accept questions of this nature.

Comment: @PareshMayani - It depends on the kind of question.

Comment: @Oded yes it always depend of the kind of question but here he would want to ask questions regarding Data model and software architecture so as far as I know it belongs to Programmers SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not on stackoverflow. This seems like an appropriate quesiton for [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/about).

Ask about...

- Specific issues with software development, for instance:

  - algorithm and data structure concepts
  - testing and quality assurance
  - development methodologies
- freelancing and business concerns
- software architecture, engineering, or licensing

Comment: If it belongs on a whiteboard - Programmers is probably a good place. If it has code, probably [so].

Comment: Don't forget [Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149/are-database-design-reviews-in-scope) (and potentially DBA.SE, but that's not entirely clear to me).

Comment: @Mat - The distinction there is - if it is a whole piece of (working) code that one wants to improve on, code review. If it is SQL (complex SQL) and/or related to database administration, DBA is the place.

Comment: @SeanWM I point out this for my case: "algorithm and data structure concepts"